# Angular $http 404 status

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular, I have created a web API Rest service and a simple client making get requests.

it works fine when calling localhost but when I move it to a different server I get 404 statuses, even though I can see a 200 status in fiddler and the JSON I need.

The two requests and responses look identical, I have seen all the posts on about removing headers which I have done.

I am using Angular 1.2.10 and JQuery 1.11.0

Does anyone know of any other issues I am missing.

```
typescript class being called
  export class SearchService {
    http: ng.IHttpService;

    constructor($http) {
      this.http = $http;
    }
    SearchPages(successCallback: Function, searchFor: string): void {
      delete this.http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
      this.http.get("http://www.?????.com/????/api/search/" + searchFor).success(function (data, status) {
        successCallback(data);
      }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
          var tt: string = "Error";
        });
    }
  }
```

many thanks

Comment: have a look at your chrome devtool's "network" panel, it could be a CORS pre-flight problem. for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Likely a CORS issue with your server side Web Api. I'm guessing you're using ASP.NET, if so, try this

1. Manage NuGet packages for solution => Microsoft ASP.NET Web Api 2.1 Cross-Origin Support
2. WebApiConfig.cs

---

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace MyAwesomeProject
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

            config.EnableCors(cors);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```